# "computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run" in Android 4: What does this mean?

Tags: android

my Android 4 app generates long views by adding multiple `textviews` to a `linearlayout`. This works well for all my list items, except of one. The problem is, that the list of `textviews` aborts after adding the first `textview`, but no exception is thrown!

I just see this warning in my LogCat:

> TextLayoutCache | computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single
>   run

Does anyone know what that means?

Comment: harfbuzz is the font/OpenType rendering engine, used in Firefox amongst others. TextLayoutCache is a native component in Android. What the hell did you put in that TextView :-P .. you should probably file a bug if it's not completely off the wall. Edit: It isn't the [same as this?](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23465)

Comment: I debuged all the variables. There's just an empty string inside this textview which seems to be corrupted in some way... Curiously, my app is working right now. I just restarted the VM (computer). Maybe it was some kind of corrupted VM state which created this issue. Hopefully this never happens again, but with saying this, it propably will ;)

Comment: I got it too, without any verify errors.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using a `ListView` instead of a `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HarfBuzz is a layout/shaping engine for OpenType fonts. Its purpose is to standardize text layout in Open-source projects. That warning, can be traced back to [android/graphics/TextLayoutCache.cpp](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/CyanogenMod/AndroidFrameworksBase/core/jni/android/graphics/TextLayoutCache.cpp#447).

The relevant code block is:

```
ubidi_setPara(bidi, chars, contextCount, bidiReq, NULL, &status); //runs the algorithm
int paraDir = ubidi_getParaLevel(bidi) & kDirection_Mask; // 0 if ltr, 1 if rtl

     if (U_SUCCESS(status) && rc == 1) {
           // Normal case: one run, status is ok
           isRTL = (paraDir == 1);
           useSingleRun = true;
      } else if (!U_SUCCESS(status) || rc < 1) {
           LOGW("computeValuesWithHarfbuzz -- need to force to single run");
           isRTL = (paraDir == 1);
           useSingleRun = true;
      } else {...}
```

This part of the code is a part of the BiDi algorithm (uBiDi) which stands for Unicode Bidirectional, as detailed [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

Data in Arabic, Hebrew or another RTL languages need handling of bidirectional text.  Because these right-to-left scripts use digits that are written from left to right, the text is actually bidirectional: a mixture of right-to-left and left-to-right text.

`rc` in the above is the [runcount](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html#getRunCount%28%29) of the algorithm. Each unicode character is assigned a level. (Even the unassigned ones)

Text is first split into different levels, (Level 0 is plain English text, Level 1 is plain Arabic text, possibly embedded within English level 0 text, etc)

The runs now occur in the following manner.

```
 Levels:  0   0   0   1   1   1   2

 Runs:   <--- 1 ---> <--- 2 ---> <3>
```

Run count in the above example is 3. 
The warning is thrown if the BiDi algorithm hasn't been able to run even once successfully. There are many [errors](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/utypes_8h.html#a3343c1c8a8377277046774691c98d78c) that can occur, preventing the successful running of the algorithm.
Any one of these could've triggered the warning.

**However, whether the warning occurs or not, the code behaviour is exactly identical except for the warning logged. So, it shouldn't affect the running of the application.**

Comment: Thanks Anirudh, perfect answer!